# BLDC Motor and Generator, query about capacitor bank

Tags: generator, brushless-dc-motor

I have 3 phase generator (believe to be Wye) which goes to 6 diode rectifier, the rpm can goes from 1000 to 5000.

The output of the rectifer (50V say) has ripple on top which goes to 100W Motor driver BLDC. The BLDC motor is being used for position control (ie CDC).

Is there guideline or equation how much capacitance necessary to smooth out the BLDC motor for reliable operation (speaking generally). I'm unclear how much smoothing it really needs.

Comment: switching frequency of the control circuit, and what an acceptable level of ripple are two things you should mention/specify. Also, nothing wrong with ball-parking some bulk capacitance and doing some testing and removing caps until you reach the desired ripple and using that in the final unit.

Comment: Yes there is, but you need to come up with a model for your circuit first. The ripple and smoothing is up to you, does it interfere with operation?